# Flex/AS3: why I failed to listen ready event of module

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, module

follow are code snippet

```
       var depTree:IModuleInfo=ModuleManager.getModule('modules/depTree.swf');
        if(!depTree.loaded){
            depTree.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.ERROR, onModuleError);
            depTree.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.PROGRESS,onModuleProgress);
            depTree.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.SETUP,onModuleSetup);
            depTree.addEventListener(ModuleEvent.READY,onDepTreeModuleReady);
            depTree.load();
        }

    private function onDepTreeModuleReady(event:ModuleEvent):void{
        logger.debug("depTree module was ready");
        var moduleInfo:IModuleInfo = event.currentTarget as IModuleInfo;
        Panel(component).addChild(moduleInfo.factory.create() as Module);
    }
```

when I run my application, I got "[SWF] modules/depTree.swf - 336,967 bytes after decompression" message,so i'm sure depTree module was loaded,also depTree.read is true.
but onDepTreeModuleReady function seems never be invoked,I didn't got debug message in it and UI of application has no change.

Answer (score 0):

Its an SDK bug move to 3.4